# What should my file watcher settings be for phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I am trying to set up file watcher in Phpstorm for watching a main.scss file and outputting to a style.css file. I am really confused. In order for me to get a macro preview in the macros screen I need to have either main.scss open or style.css open.

Is the arguments supposed to be the main.scss file and the output path supposed to be the style.css file? What should my macros be?

[What should my macros be?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb3vc.png)

[Here is my file structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2MPq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest the following setup:

```
Arguments: $FileName$
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/css/style.css
Working directory: $FileDir$
```

Make sure to also enable *Create output file from stdout*

[image]